# Check Box Selected Action in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am using M13Checkbox, and you can look at the Github page [here](https://github.com/Marxon13/M13Checkbox). In my table view function, I assign a M13 Checkbox to each cell's checkbox variable. The variable looks like this `var checkbox = M13Checkbox()` in my custom cell class.

This is what the code where I define the checkbox inside the table view looks:

```
cell.checkbox = M13Checkbox(frame: CGRect(x: 15.0, y: (cell.center.y)-22.0, width: 20.0, height:20.0))
view.addSubview(cell.checkbox)
```

My question is how do I have an action occur when a user presses a checkbox? I want another view or a popover to come up when a checkbox is clicked. Is that possible with the way I have it set up? What code do I need to add?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

M13Checkbox is derived from UIControl, so you can use addTarget function to add a handler to an event.

```
cell.checkBox.tag = indexPath.row

cell.checkBox.addTarget(self, action: #selector(YourClassName.onValueChanged(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)

...

func onValueChanged(sender : AnyObject?)
{
  if let checkBox = sender?.view as? M13Checkbox
  {
    let row = checkBox.tag
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way that I can then find out in which row/ which cell the button was clicked?

Comment: if you want to do that, you need to store the row in the checkbox's tag property. I updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: I've also updated the handler on how to get the row number from the sender parameter.

Comment: Hey can you help me out with this error- ambiguous reference to member view (of sender) in the code above?

Comment: I updated my answer. replaced sender. in the if statement with sender?.